# Neverending Loop using Nokogiri library; can't figure out why

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to pull text from various parts of a webpage and push them to an array (one index per webpage.) The following code loops forever and I can't figure out why:

```
def pull_text(urls)
  results = []
  urls.each do |something|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(something))
    main_text = doc.xpath('//div[@class="modText"]').inner_text
    blue_text =  doc.xpath('//div[@class="Text color2"]').inner_text
    grey_text =  doc.xpath('//div[@class="Text color1"]').inner_text
    table_text = doc.xpath('//div[@class="Table color"]').inner_text
    all_text = main_text + blue_text + grey_text + table_text
    results << all_text
  end
end
```

I also noted that when I don't assign the doc.xpath lines to variables, it'll run without looping forever, but I can't figure how to otherwise shove all that into an array.

However, I did notice that when I feed a single url to the method, it works. However, I need the method to be able to process multiple urls, not just one.

```
def grab_text(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  main_text = doc.xpath('//div[@class="modText"]').inner_text
  blue_text =  doc.xpath('//div[@class="Text color2"]').inner_text
  grey_text =  doc.xpath('//div[@class="Text color1"]').inner_text
  table_text = doc.xpath('//div[@class="Table color"]').inner_text
  all_text = main_text + blue_text + grey_text + table_text
end
```

Sorry for the not-so-awesome design. I'm rusty and am still kind of new at programming. :S

Comment: I think you're just confused about return values. The first method should probably return results, correct? The way it's written will return urls.

Comment: As noted there is a problem with the returned value, but I don't see why it should loop forever. Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Please post a couple of the URLs which you are using for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern *empty array + each + push + return array* (that last thing was missing in your code) -> `map` (more on functional programming with Ruby [here](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming))

```
def pull_text(urls)
  urls.map do |url|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    main_text = doc.xpath('//div[@class="modText"]').inner_text
    blue_text =  doc.xpath('//div[@class="Text color2"]').inner_text
    grey_text =  doc.xpath('//div[@class="Text color1"]').inner_text
    table_text = doc.xpath('//div[@class="Table color"]').inner_text
    main_text + blue_text + grey_text + table_text
  end
end
```

Abstracting common patterns:

```
def pull_text(urls)
  urls.map do |url|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    ["modText", "Text color2", "Text color1", "Table color"].map do |klass|
      doc.xpath("//div[@class='#{klass}']").inner_text
    end.join
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

@pguardiario, is correct. In Ruby methods the last line or return value of the block is implicitly returned. So in your case you were returning the return value of `urls.each` instead of `results`.

However that being said, here is a more idiomatic way of writing it using the [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

I use the following methods from Enumerable - [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) in the below code snippet.

```
TEXT_XPATHS = [ '//div[@class="modText"]',
                '//div[@class="Text color2"]',
                '//div[@class="Text color1"]',
                '//div[@class="Table color"]' ]                  

# 
# extract_text_from( a_single_url )
#
# extract_text_from( ["a", "list", "of", "urls"] )
#
def extract_text_from(urls)
  Array(urls).inject([]) do |results, url|
    html = Nokogiri::HTML( open(url) )

    texts = TEXT_XPATHS.map { |xpath| html.xpath(xpath).inner_text }

    results << texts.join
  end
end
```

Comment: be careful, you are emulating map with inject!

Comment: and array.reduce(:+) -> array.join

Comment: @tokland: `texts.join` :-). Could you elaborate why using map within inject is a problem as I'm not mapping on the injected array. Am i missing something ?

Comment: yeah, sorry texts.join. The other matter: no, there is no problem with the TEXT_XPATHS.map, the problem is that you are writing xs.inject([]) { |output, x| output << f(x) }. That's xs.map { |x| f(x) }

Comment: @tokland: you are right, they are equivalent. Btw I meant I updated to `texts.join` instead of `text.reduce(:+)` after your comment :-). Cheers.